# FaCT++ reasoner for OWL Protege

Tags: owl, protege, protege4, fact++

I downloaded OWL Protege 4.3.
I built an ontology and I want to check the consistency of a given configuration.

I'm totally new to the software and I don't know how to use faCT++ with OWL protege.
I can see that I can select a reasoner from "Reasoner > FaCt++" but what should I do then?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the reasoner after having selected it. The command is in the same menu.